# Redirect one tab to another

Tags: apex, visualforce, redirect

So I have tried to find the infromation online, and all I can find is information using standard controllers to display custom data.

I simply want to redirect one tab to another. So for example, when someone clicks "Orders" I don't want it to load to the Orders tab. I want it to instead load the contents of the "Requests" tab, and I want to hide the original "Orders" tab contents.

I figured out how to display rows and columns, but nothing for just getting the contents of one tab to load when you click the other. Would someone be able to help point me in the right direction? Or show me what code I should actually use to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you even have an orders tab if you just want the user to click on a request tab? And what do you mean by "tab"? This question just really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: By "Tab" I mean the tabs along the top of Salesforce (Account, Contact, Opportunities, etc...) that provide access to the objects for users. We have both because we were originally going to use one, and then an app was installed that brought it's own object with it for doing the same thing. However, the original object is being held onto "in case it's needed" in the future.

Sorry it doesn't make more sense....

Comment: So just remove permissions to the "old" object or hide the tab in profiles and it won't show up. Direct your users to the new tab instead. If you ever need to bring it back, just give permissions back and it will reappear.

Comment: If you want to preserve the `Orders` tab for legacy reasons, you can override the tab with a VF page that uses a page Action method that redirects to the `Requests` tab. see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_customize_override.htm

Comment: @cropredy I'll remember that for future issues with this, thank you very much. For now I deleted the tab for Orders, but retained the object itself (corp wanted to keep the object intact). I created a VisualForce page that displays a view for Requests with specific information, and then connected the VisualForce page to a custom tab labeled "Orders." The idea was to keep users using an "Orders" tab even though they were working in requests.

Really appreciate the advice!